# How to perform form validations in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Here on submit i am returning error if form is not valid,i checked like form.email == '' and this is ok if my fields are less .What if i have 10 fields.Can someone suggest help please............

My template,

```
  <form id="login-form" name="loginform" class="nobottommargin" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value,loginform)" novalidate>
  <div class="col_full"> 
     <input type="email" [formControl]="form.controls['email']" id="login-form-username" name="login-form-username" value="" placeholder="username" class="form-control not-dark formcontrolheight" ngModel required>

  </div>
  <div *ngIf="submitted && !form.controls['email'].valid">
     <div  class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Email is required</strong>
    </div>
   </div> 
<div *ngIf ="form.controls['email'].touched" >
      <div *ngIf = "!form.controls['email'].valid" class = "alert alert-danger">
          <strong>Please enter a valid email</strong>
      </div></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="col_full">
     <input type="password" [formControl]="form.controls['phone']" id="login-form-password" name="login-form-password" value="" placeholder="password" class="form-control not-dark formcontrolheight" ngModel required>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="submitted && !form.controls['phone'].valid" >
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Password is required</strong>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="col_full nobottommargin">
     <button class="col-xs-12 button button-mini loginbuttoncss  nomargin" id="login-form-submit" name="login-form-submit" value="login">Login</button>
  </div>
```

My ts,

```
export class Login implements OnInit{
form: FormGroup;
submitted = false;
directives: [SignUp]
constructor(public location: Location,public router: Router, public http: Http, fbld: FormBuilder,public toastr: ToastsManager) {
    this.form = fbld.group({
        email: ['', emailValidator],
        phone: ['', Validators.required]
    });

}
ngOnInit() {
    var str = localStorage.getItem('social');
    var loc = JSON.parse(str);
    if(this.location.path().indexOf('/login') == -1){
        jQuery('#header.sticky-header').show();
        jQuery('#content .content-wrap').addClass('nopadding');
    }else{
        jQuery('#header.sticky-header').hide();
        jQuery('#content .content-wrap').removeClass('nopadding');
}
    }

onSubmit(form: any,formname) {
    console.log(form.email);
      this.submitted =true;
      if(form.email == '' || form.phone ==''){

            return ;
        }
     this.submitted =false;
   var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    this.http.post('http://localhost/a2server/index.php/profile/logIn', JSON.stringify(form), { headers: headers })
        .subscribe(
        response => {
            if (response.json().error_code == 0) {
             //   console.log(response.json().data[0].profile_id);
                if (response.json().data[0].profile_id) {
                    localStorage.setItem('social', JSON.stringify(response.json().data[0]));
                }
                this.toastr.success('Loggedin successfully');
                this.router.navigate(['/demo/profile']);
            }
            else {
                this.toastr.error('Loggedin failed');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Comment: Thanks Harry,I have gone through that but i didnt see anything that is usefull in my case..........

Comment: If you have 20 minutes, this talk will help A LOT in how you design forms & validations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihYc9y7dQA0 The code may be outdated but the concept still remains relevant until RC5.

Comment: I recommend you follow one of the guides suggested by Harry Ninh (or find something more to your taste, maybe this is better? http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/) because onSubmit() isn't leveraging the framework as intended.  The formbuilder is there to manage validation rules and you're halfway there.  The guides will talk about using the valid/touched/dirty attributes on the fields to help when submitting.